# Cannot send a SMS with gammu (error 500, message reference=-1)

Tags: gsm, gammu

I've been playing with gammu and Huawei USB modem:

### lsusb  | grep Huawei

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

The modem is capable of receiving SMS, but sending does not work.

### Problematic command

```
gammu sendsms TEXT 728123456 -text "text"
If you want break, press Ctrl+C...
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..error 500, message reference=-1
Unknown error.
```

### gammu monitor

According to monitor, signal and other info about network, etc. are fine.

```
SIM phonebook        :  12 used, 238 free
Dialled numbers      :   0 used,  10 free
Received numbers     :   0 used,  10 free
Missed numbers       :   0 used,  10 free
Own numbers          :   0 used,   4 free
Phone phonebook      :   0 used, 100 free
Battery level        : 100 percent
Charge state         : powered from battery
Signal strength      : -73 dBm
Network level        : 60 percent
SIM SMS status       : 3 used, 0 unread, 10 locations
Phone SMS status     : 0 used, 0 unread, 255 locations
Network state        : home network
Network              : 230 02 (O2, Czech Republic), LAC 1, CID 
Name in phone        : "EUROTEL - CZ"
Packet network state : home network
Packet network       : 230 02 (O2, Czech Republic), LAC , CID 
Name in phone        : "EUROTEL - CZ"
GPRS                 : attached

SIM phonebook        :  12 used, 238 free
Dialled numbers      :   0 used,  10 free
Received numbers     :   0 used,  10 free
Missed numbers       :   0 used,  10 free
Own numbers          :   0 used,   4 free
Phone phonebook      :   0 used, 100 free
Battery level        : 100 percent
Charge state         : powered from battery
Signal strength      : -73 dBm
Network level        : 60 percent
SIM SMS status       : 3 used, 0 unread, 10 locations
Phone SMS status     : 0 used, 0 unread, 255 locations
Network state        : home network
Network              : 230 02 (O2, Czech Republic), LAC 1, CID 
Name in phone        : "EUROTEL - CZ"
Packet network state : home network
Packet network       : 230 02 (O2, Czech Republic), LAC , CID 
Name in phone        : "EUROTEL - CZ"
GPRS                 : attached
```

Following output is provided by gammu log file with textall Logformat.

### gammu log

```
[Gammu            - 1.37.0]
[Connection       - "at"]
[Connection index - 0]
[Model type       - ""]
[Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
[Running on       - Linux, kernel 4.5.2-1-default (#1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 21 09:07:52 UTC 2016 (0454a6e))]
Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is down, CTS is up
Setting speed to 115200
[Module           - "auto"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "UCS2""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x20/32
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  : "UCS2"....OK..
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x2F/47
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C, S: ("IRA","GSM",
22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      "UCS2")....OK.. 
Chosen GSM as normal charset
Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0E/14
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D          AT+CSCS="GSM".  
1 "AT+CSCS="GSM""
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0D |0A  AT+CSCS="GSM"...
4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
Getting model
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D                                  AT+CGMM.        
1 "AT+CGMM"
2 "E1750"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x17/23
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D |0D |0A |45E|311|377|355|300|0D  AT+CGMM...E1750.
0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                      ...OK..         
[Model name: `E1750']
[Model data: `E1750']
[Model data: `E1750']
[Connected model  - "E1750"]
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 "QUALCOMM INCORPORATED"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x27/39
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |51Q|55U|41A|4CL|43C|4FO AT+CGMI...QUALCO
4DM|4DM|20 |49I|4EN|43C|4FO|52R|50P|4FO|52R|41A|54T|45E|44D|0D  MM INCORPORATED.
0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                      ...OK..         
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: Qualcomm]
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
[Module           - "A2D|iPAQ|at|M20|S25|MC35|TC35|C35i|S65|S300|5110|5130|5190|5210|6110|6130|6150|6190|6210|6250|6310|6310i|6510|7110|8210|8250|8290|8310|8390|8850|8855|8890|8910|9110|9210"]
Escaping SMS mode
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x02/2
1B |0D                                                          ..              
Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x03/3
41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
1 "AT"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Enabling echo
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x05/5
41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
1 "ATE1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Trying Motorola mode switch
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
1 "AT+MODE=2"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x13/19
41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO AT+MODE=2...ERRO
52R|0D |0A                                                      R..             
Seems not to be supported
Enabling CME errors
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
1 "AT+CMEE=1"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
1 "AT+CSCS?"
2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x1F/31
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
1 "AT+CSCS=?"
2 "+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x2F/47
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C, S: ("IRA","GSM",
22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      "UCS2")....OK.. 
Chosen GSM as normal charset
Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
1 "AT+CGMI"
2 "QUALCOMM INCORPORATED"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x27/39
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |51Q|55U|41A|4CL|43C|4FO AT+CGMI...QUALCO
4DM|4DM|20 |49I|4EN|43C|4FO|52R|50P|4FO|52R|41A|54T|45E|44D|0D  MM INCORPORATED.
0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                      ...OK..         
Manufacturer info received
[Manufacturer: Qualcomm]
Checking for OBEX support
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
1 "AT+CPROT=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x14/20
41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R AT+CPROT=?...ERR
4FO|52R|0D |0A                                                  OR..            
Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0C/12
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x15/21
41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E|52R AT+SYNCML=?...ER
52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                              ROR..           
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0D/13
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x16/22
41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |45E AT$TSSPCSW=?...E
52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                          RROR..          
Setting date & time
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x21/33
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|322|300|311|366|2F/|300|355 AT+CCLK="2016/05
2F/|311|311|2C,|311|311|3A:|322|355|3A:|322|333|2B+|300|311|22" /11,11:25:23+01"
0D                                                              .               
1 "AT+CCLK="2016/05/11,11:25:23+01""
2 "ERROR"
Checking line: ERROR
AT reply state: 3
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x2A/42
41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3D=|22"|322|300|311|366|2F/|300|355 AT+CCLK="2016/05
2F/|311|311|2C,|311|311|3A:|322|355|3A:|322|333|2B+|300|311|22" /11,11:25:23+01"
0D |0D |0A |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                          ...ERROR..      
Getting firmware versions
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x08/8
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D                                  AT+CGMR.        
1 "AT+CGMR"
2 "SSD_M6281A-0.0.1   1  [Oct 02 2008 07:00:00]"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x3E/62
41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|52R|0D |0D |0A |53S|53S|44D|5F_|4DM|366 AT+CGMR...SSD_M6
322|388|311|41A|2D-|300|2E.|300|2E.|311|20 |20 |20 |311|20 |20  281A-0.0.1   1  
5B[|4FO|63c|74t|20 |300|322|20 |322|300|300|388|20 |300|377|3A: [Oct 02 2008 07:
300|300|3A:|300|300|5D]|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A          00:00]....OK..  
Received firmware version: "SSD_M6281A-0.0.1   1  [Oct 02 2008 07:00:00]"
Number version is "62810.011022"
[Firmware version - "SSD_M6281A-0.0.1   1  [Oct 02 2008 07:00:00]"]
[Connected]
Checking used: UDH len 0, UsedBytes 0, FreeText 160, UsedText 0, FreeBytes 140
Adding text
Copy 160 (max 4)
Defalt text, length 4 4
Text added
Checking at the end: UDH len 0, UsedBytes 4, FreeText 156, UsedText 4, FreeBytes 136
4 4
Entering GSM_GetSMSC
Getting SMSC
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x09/9
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCA?.       
1 "AT+CSCA?"
2 "+CSCA: "+85290000000",145"
3 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x2C/44
41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|41A AT+CSCA?...+CSCA
3A:|20 |22"|2B+|388|355|322|399|300|300|300|300|300|300|300|22" : "+85290000000"
2C,|311|344|355|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                  ,145....OK..    
SMSC info received
Parsing +CSCA: "+85290000000",145 with +CSCA: @p, @i
Grabbed string from reply: "+85290000000" (parsed 14 bytes)
Parsed phone string "+85290000000"
Phone string decoded as "+85290000000"
Parsed int 145
Leaving GSM_GetSMSC
Entering GSM_SendSMS
Trying SMS PDU mode
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0A/10
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|46F|3D=|300|0D                          AT+CMGF=0.      
1 "AT+CMGF=0"
2 "OK"
Checking line: OK
AT reply state: 1
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x10/16
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|46F|3D=|300|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMGF=0...OK..
SMS Submit
Recipient number "728119904"
SMSC number "+85290000000"
SMS class -1
SMS validity ff
TPMR: 00 0
7 bit SMS, length 4, 4
text
Waiting for modem prompt
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x0B/11
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|377|0D                      AT+CMGS=17.     
1 "AT+CMGS=17"
2 "> "
Checking line: > 
AT reply state: 7
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x0F/15
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|377|0D |0D |0A |3E>|20      AT+CMGS=17...>  
Sending SMS
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x32/50
300|377|399|311|355|388|399|322|300|300|300|300|300|300|46F|300 07915892000000F0
311|311|300|300|300|399|388|311|322|377|311|388|399|311|300|399 1100098127189109
46F|344|300|300|300|300|46F|46F|300|344|46F|344|333|322|399|45E F40000FF04F4329E
300|45E                                                         0E              
SENDING frame type 0x00/length 0x01/1
1A                                                              .               
Leaving GSM_SendSMS
1 "AT+CMGS=17"
2 "> 07915892000000F01100098127189109F40000FF04F4329E0E"
3 "+CMS ERROR: 500"
Checking line: +CMS ERROR: 500
AT reply state: 5
RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x56/86
41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|47G|53S|3D=|311|377|0D |0D |0A |3E>|20 |300 AT+CMGS=17...> 0
377|399|311|355|388|399|322|300|300|300|300|300|300|46F|300|311 7915892000000F01
311|300|300|300|399|388|311|322|377|311|388|399|311|300|399|46F 100098127189109F
344|300|300|300|300|46F|46F|300|344|46F|344|333|322|399|45E|300 40000FF04F4329E0
45E|0D |0A |0D |0A |2B+|43C|4DM|53S|20 |45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|3A: E....+CMS ERROR:
20 |355|300|300|0D |0A                                           500..          
Error 500
Sent SMS on device: "/dev/ttyUSB0"
CMS Error 500: "unknown error"
[Terminating]
[Closing]
```

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was caused by wrong phone number of my operator's SMS center.

After that, gammu works fine:

```
If you want break, press Ctrl+C...
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=207
```

Comment: I got the same problem, what is the  "phone number of my operator's SMS center" ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same error message is caused if the recipient's phone number is invalid. In my country the operator does not accept anything else but numbers, so having dash or whitespace or slashes throw the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Gammu has been working on my raspberry since 2018 with a 3G-dongle huawei E169. It was along, not connected to any network. He sent and received sms even after a reboot.
Since mid October it stopped working... no more sms in or out. I tested the SIM card with my operator (Free) and it looks ok. I know that 2G-network is almost stopped but my dongle is supposed to be 3G...
I'm now try to make it run on another raspberry3. I start install from stratch and now it looks like :

```
> sudo gammu identify
Device : /dev/ttyUSB-3G
Manufacturer : Huawei
Model : E169 (E169)
Firmware : 11.314.09.50.00
IMEI : 353xxx
SIM IMSI : 20xxx
```

Everything looks ok but when i send a sms i get this error :

```
> gammu -d textall -f /home/pi/TraceSms sendsms TEXT 06xx -text « coucou »
If you want break, press Ctrl+C…
Sending SMS 1/1…waiting for network answer…error 500, message reference=-1
Unknown error.
```

I got a 394 lines trace with an error but I'm not able to understand... Any help ?
Merci beaucoup ;-)